# How do I set up relationships/queries in this case?

Tags: microsoft-access

I'm gonna say that I'm a beginner trying to learn by doing.

I'm trying to create a database to manage the registration of a summer camp.  I started putting it together before I had all the paperwork, so that may be an issue.  Right now I have four tables (IEP, Medical, Papers, and Permissions).  Right now the only populated table is the Papers one (it had papers necessary for registration in the program).  I have set up a query and report so I can see who is missing which piece of paperwork, but now I have to include IEP, Medical, and Permissions.  How can I link the Papers table (which has each childs' name) with the three new tables?  Would I need to use forms and subforms to enter the data in the new tables?  Or would it be better to combine all the information in one table?  Ideally I would like to be able to just pull up a child's name from a combo box and enter data as needed, but I'm not quite sure how to do that yet.  I feel like there is something I am missing about relationships, keys, and queries, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: This was quite some time ago, so I am not sure if this is still relevant to you in any way. It would seem to me that you have perhaps not designed your tables very well. I don't know what an IEP is (Individual Education Program?) and it is a stretch to assume people here would. It would seem that a critical table would be "Child". All other tables would have ChildID in them, possibly unique. The thing you have to ask yourself is - do I need one or MORE of these per child? If it is only ever one, it can go directly into the Child table. Even address could go into a new table due to siblings.

Comment: This example might help too... http://superuser.com/questions/937131/in-ms-access-how-can-a-form-provide-a-drop-down-populated-with-data-from-a-rela/938220#938220